# Rails/Postgres: column must appear in the GROUP BY clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a scope that joins users to posts, to get only users that have visible posts.  This works in MySQL, but PG is a lot more strict, and throws an error.

User Model:

```
belongs_to :account

scope :have_posts, joins(:posts).where('posts.visible => true').group('users.id')
```

Controller:

```
@account.users.have_posts.each do |user|
  # do stuff
end
```

Error:

> (PGError: ERROR:  column "users.account_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function: SELECT     "users".* FROM       "users"  INNER JOIN "posts" ON "posts"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE     ("users".account_id = 1) AND (recommendations.approved = true) GROUP BY  users.id)

It's complaining about "users.account_id" which is from calling `@account.users` (as I obviously don't want all users in the DB).

Any idea how to fix?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is the `GROUP BY` clause. If you use this, you cannot select any non-aggregated fields, so `SELECT "users".* [...]` doesn't work. From the Postgres docs:

> In general, if a table is grouped, columns that are not used in the
>   grouping cannot be referenced except in aggregate expressions.

Something like this may work, although messy:

```
scope :have_posts, 
  joins('inner join (select user_id from posts where visible = true group by user_id) users_with_posts on users_with_posts.user_id=users.id')
```

One alternative would be to specify every selected field using aggregate functions like `MAX` or `MIN`, but this will probably make the scope even longer and less versatile.

Answer (score 0):

This should be expressed as `where` condition not `joins`, because there is no need for any data from `posts`. IMHO much easier to read:

```
scope :have_posts, -> {
  where(
    'EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM posts p WHERE p.id = users.id AND visible = true)'
  )
}
```

Ruby 2 and Rails 3/4 ready. PG optimizer will take care to run it as fast as possible.